# Get int representation NTL GF2E

Tags: ntl

How I will be able to get the int representation in Galois Field using NTL library. For example of element

```
GF2E xx=random_GF2E();
```

I'm trying use

```
printf("%d",xx._GF2E__rep.HexOutput);
```

but I get 0

Answer (score 1):

GF2E is an extension field, i.e. the elements in GF2E are living in `GF(2)[X]/(P)`, where `P` is an irreducable polynomial. So you can not get an integer representation. But you can get a representation as a vector.

```
GF2X P;
SetCoeff(P, 0, 1);
SetCoeff(P, 1, 1);
SetCoeff(P, 2, 1);
// P is now x^2+x+1, this is irreducable since P(1)=1 and P(0)=1

GF2E::init(P);
GF2E xx = random_GF2E();

cout << xx << endl;     // Prints something like "[0 1]"
```

*Notice*: To use this code snippet, you have to import the namespaces `NTL` and `std` to your programm by using `using namespace NTL;` and `using namespace std;` after your includes.
An other way would be to add `NTL::` to all the NTL functions and `std::` to `cout` and `endl`.
See [this tutorial](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/namespaces/) for more information about namespaces.

Comment: Is there a way to get the integer representation of that vector? i.e. in a way that the highest degree coefficient is the MSB of that integer and the coefficient of x^0 is the LSB? when using the method BytesFromGF2X it results in a weird representation which is neither big endian nor little endian

Comment: @Bush The Elements in `GF2E` are not numbers but polynomials. so the vector represents the exponents. I think there is no canonical way of representing this polynomials as an integer.